# ctrl+alt+f7 and ctrl+alt+f8 not changing back into the X session!

Tags: boot, grub2, tty

I have Ubuntu 12.04 lts and I want was opening my pc and after the grub menu, the screen went purple. Ubuntu didn't load after that and the hard drive activity stopped. So I restarted the pc inti recovery with Linux and ran dpkj and fsck to check file system.  It doesn't help, so I clicked on recovery ( the last option on the grub menu). It replied:

```
Error: file not found
Error: file not found
Error: load kernel first
```

I don't have windows or any other OS. So in recovery mode I enabled networking and when it finished, it directed me to tty1 so I pressed <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> and <kbd>F8</kbd> but nothing happened. Now it always directs me to the tty1 and I cannot access the GUI or X mode.

Please help.  I am really in trouble with this.

Comment: from tty1 try `startx`

Comment: What is `dpkj`?

Comment: Can you now boot or not? Can you reach a working command line? What happens if you run `sudo service lightdm start` from the tty?

Comment: @AvinashRaj I guess DPKG. (It's labeled "fix broken packages" or something like this.)

Answer (score 6):

It's because you don't have a X session running, try to start a fresh one with

```
startx
```

Alternatively try to start the display manager (as suggested by [user31389](https://askubuntu.com/users/31389/user31389))

```
service lightdm start
```

Comment: Recovery mode always starts without an X server. As an alternative to startx (which will run X server directly) one can start display manager like lightdm (or GDM in Ubuntu Gnome or whatever DM you use) like this: `service lightdm start`. No sudo required, because in recovery mode you are logged in as root. Of course in this case you need to fix your other problems. Starting X server won't help you if you can't boot Ubuntu normally in the first place.

Answer (score 4):

There can be many things wrong here. You have to find the source of the problem. I suspect something happened to the boot partition and/or root partition. Try

- enter recovery mode and check the partitions mounted:

> root@localhost:# df
>
> you should see something like:
>
> ```
>  Sist.fichs     1K-blocos      Ocup    Livres Uso% Montado em     
>  /dev/sda1       39241336  30366172   6858756  82% /              
>  /dev/sda3      433336096 178292700 233008148  44% /home
> ```

- the first column shows the partitions

  - `/dev/sda1` is my first partition on my first disk
  - `/dev/sda3` is my third partition on my first disk
- the last column shows where the partitions are mounted

  - `/` OS partition
  - `/home` users  home directories partition

You probably have a different partitions layout, but what's important is that you need to be able to:

1. load and boot the kernel (GRUB needs to know where it is)
2. mount the OS partition
3. mount other partitions that may exist, especially the `/home` partition

If what you problem is the GRUB you can check the [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) wiki page for more info. But if not, you need to check if you can mount the partitions (if not already mounted) with `mount /dev/sdX# /`

If you can manually mount the partitions, it's possible that the `/etc/fstab` is broken and you need to correct it. Check [Fstab](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Fstab) for more info.

#### Good luck

Answer (score 2):

From the virtual terminals, try just <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>, no control.  That might work for you provided the X server is still running.