# Directory /etc/X11/X is empty! Login directs to tty

Tags: 12.04, symbolic-link, ltsp

I have Ubuntu 12.04 lts and my pc is down for a long time. Not like with hardware. I have asked a few questions about this. Here are their links.
[ctrl+alt+f7 and ctrl+alt+f8 not changing back into the X session!](https://askubuntu.com/questions/435625/ctrlaltf7-and-ctrlaltf8-not-changing-back-into-the-x-session)
[How do I bypass The TTY login on ubuntu 12.04 lts and what is it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/435135/how-do-i-bypass-the-tty-login-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts-and-what-is-it)

So. Now I realised that the X directory is empty. Any one knows how to add a symbolic link to the directory? I have tried startx. It says no symbolic link. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

/etc/X11/X is not a directory! Right now on my machine it is a symlink to Xorg big binary file. Your problem is somewhere else. 
For the refrence, here is my `/etc/X11` list:

```
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root      344 марта 23 10:23 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root     4684 марта 28 21:08 ..
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root      676 марта 23 10:23 app-defaults
-rw------- 1 root root 36941824 марта 23 23:28 core
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root      110 окт.  16 23:03 cursors
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root       18 окт.  16 23:03 default-display-manager
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root       18 окт.  16 23:01 fonts
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root       24 марта 23 10:23 ja_JP.eucJP
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root       24 марта 23 10:23 ja_JP.UTF-8
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    17394 дек.   3  2009 rgb.txt
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       13 марта 15 22:52 X -> /usr/bin/Xorg
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root       48 окт.  16 23:03 xinit
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root        0 мая   17  2013 xkb
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      709 апр.   1  2010 Xreset
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root       12 окт.  16 23:02 Xreset.d
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root       20 окт.  16 23:02 Xresources
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     3730 марта 22  2012 Xsession
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root      816 марта 15 23:14 Xsession.d
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root      265 июля   1  2008 Xsession.options
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root       13 июня   5  2013 XvMCConfig
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root      601 окт.  16 23:02 Xwrapper.config
```

Comment: Then how do I fix it. I can't login to my normal Xmode!

Comment: What should I do?